# Convert broken characters into proper values in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, jsoup

I am currently reading from an external XML file.

The apostrophe character ’ is rendered as â€™ and é (e with accent) is represented as Ã© in the RSS feed I'm reading from in my Android app which is reading from song titles and musical artist names.

My current code reads from the XML, but the original XML files has issues with representing these characters and more. This doesn't always happen, but I'd like to figure out how to read this correctly. Do I change the encoding of the XML from within Java or is there a way to convert these sorts of characters to what they should be?

EDIT: As it turns out, viewing the XML page in UTF-8 renders the characters correctly. Is there any way to read the XML document in UTF-8 encoding using the Jsoup library?

Comment: Check your encoding for the xml and check what the RSS expects.

Answer (score 3):

By defulat `Jsoup` will use `Content-Type` in the http header to render the file, but you can explicitly pass an encoding type to the `Jsoup.parse()` method like this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(yourXML, "UTF-8");
```